# Is is possible to add placeholder text to user input textbox?

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, chatbot

Is it possible to add a placeholder text in the user input textbox?

I saw that Microsoft has this in their Office365 support chatbot seen here

[image]

You will notice that it says "e.g. .... "

Is it possible to add that within the bot framework?

Comment: Why not just set the text of your textbox to an example value?  If you would like it to disappear when a user clicks within it or begins typing then setup an Event to remove the text when triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the BotFramework's **WebChat** control, and some vanilla javascript:

```
var input = document.getElementsByClassName("wc-shellinput")[0];
input.placeholder = "e.g. How do I install Office";
```

Result:

[image]